# Count pageviews on two specific pages

Tags: google-analytics

I've been searching around for an answer to this *simple* question, but can't seem to find anything even remotely related to a solution.

We've just redesigned the structure of our site, and have introduced two new pages to advertise jobs, e.g.

- mydomain.co.uk/company/ourteam
- mydomain.co.uk/company/opportunities

I'd like to see in Google Analytics how many times each page is being viewed per month.
I've searched in *Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages* but can only see filters relating to AdWords.

Can anyone please advise where to set this up, or how to isolate the content?

As a real bonus, it would be great the see this figure as a percentage of overall visitors (e.g. 8% of site visitors checked out one or more of the new pages).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is not "Conversions > Goals > Goal-URLs" what you want? Possibly GOAL is called differently, I don't see the english g:Analytics - it's the first option under the flag-icon .. my URL changes to something like [https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#report/conversions-goals-uri/**this_bit_is_specific_to_your_account**/](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#report/conversions-goals-uri/__this_bit_is_specific_to_your_account__/)

Comment: Thanks.  I was going to create a goal if no other approach was suggested. The problem is that a goal has to be created for *each separate URL*, whereas I'm happy if anybody looked at *at least one single page*, so perhaps goals are not the best thing here...?